# Which of the following matrices has the same determinant as matrix $G$

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following matrices has the  same determinant as matrix:

$G$ =  $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & 3  \\
    -2       & -3 & 2 \\
    1       & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

I could just calculate each individual determinant; however I am preparing for the CSET exam with no calculators and need to be efficient with my time.
Is there another way to identify the solution?

A.  $ \begin{bmatrix}
    -2       & -3 & 2  \\
    1       & 2 & 3\\
    1       & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

B.  $ \begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 2 & 3  \\
    -2       & -3 & 2 \\
    2       & 4 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}$

C.  $ \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 4 & 6  \\
    -2       & -3 & 2 \\
    1       & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

D.  $ \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 1 & 3  \\
    -3       & -2 & 2 \\
    2      & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You have to familiarize yourself with determinant operations, for example matrix A is matrix G with rows 1 and 2 interchanged hence determinant of A is -1 times determinant of G so A isn't the answer, same is true for C and with D (same applies to column interchanges).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find out what row and column operations are applied to $G$ in order to obtain each of the other matrices.

$A$ is obtained by swapping the first row with the second. This operation changes the sign of the determinant.

$B$ is obtained by adding the first row to the last one. This operation does not change the determinant.

$C$ is obtained by doubling the first row. The resulting determinant is the double.

$D$ is obtained by swapping the first column with the second. This operation changes the sign of the determinant.

The answer is $B$ (and no calculation is required).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the matrix $B$ is obtained from $G$ by adding $\DeclareMathOperator{Row}{Row}\Row_1(G)$ to $\Row_3(G)$. Elementary row operations of this form leave the determinant unchanged. Thus $\det B=\det G$.